# Is there a better way to programatically select a value from select2 dropdown using selenium WebDriver?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am using Selenium WebDriver to automate something. It requires filling a form that involves selecting a value from a select2 dropdown. This is the code snippet that I am using-

```
final By SELECT_DIV = By.id("s2");
click(SELECT_DIV);
final By INPUT = By.cssSelector(".select2-drop-active .select2-input");
waitForVisibilityOfElement(INPUT);
enterCharSequence(INPUT, "someData");
waitForJSandJQueryToLoad(30);//30 seconds
final By LIST_ITEM = By.cssSelector(".select2-drop-active ul.select2-results li.select2-result-selectable");
click(LIST_ITEM);
```

FYI, there are no unique ids assigned to some of these elements and hence I used css selectors for locating them.

This code works but it sometimes throws a StaleElementReferenceException. This is the error:

```
org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException: Element not found in the cache - perhaps the page has changed since it was looked up
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/stale_element_reference.html
```

Selenium version : 2.53

So, I want to know if there is any way I could avoid this. I read a few posts about it but they were not of much help.

Let me know if you need more information. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Add language tag

Answer (score 0):

'StaleElementReferenceException' means that the element has changed. It is in another div, another span or the its properties changed. Selenium may found it but it changed the very second you tried to click on it.

You need to search for the same element again and wait for it to be clickAble or visible. For example:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);          
WebElement button = 
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.
elementToBeClickable(By.id("btnLogin")));
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but in click() function that I used, I'm checking for the visibility before performing the click. My bad, I should have provided more details about implementation.